# How to reference an excel sheet by variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

I'm working on a code to reference an excel sheet by variable, however i'm stuck on the last step which is selecting the sheet according to the variable text which is the month abbreviation

It was the only way i could proceed to select the desired sheet based on the month index, any other help could be welcomed

```vb
    Dim DestWS1 As Worksheet
    Dim InputValue As Integer
    InputValue = InputBox("Please enter your month index number", "Selecting month index to generate your report")
    
    ' Print the name of the airport to the Immediate Window(Ctrl + G)

        Dim MonthIndexResult As String
        
        MonthIndexResult = _
        "=LOOKUP(" & InputValue & ",InputData!R3C17:R14C17,InputData!R3C16:R14C16)"

Set DestWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" & MonthIndexResult & ")
DestWS1.Select
```

[image]

[image]

it was the only way i could proceed to select the desired sheet based on the month index, any other help could be welcomed

Comment: Have you considered the indirect() function - builds a working link from text and a cell reference. Many examples on here.

Comment: `MonthIndexResult = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Inputvalue, 1), "mmm")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Identify Worksheet By Partial Name

```vb
Sub SelectByMonth()

    Dim InputString As String
    InputString = InputBox("Please enter your month index number", _
        "Selecting month index to generate your report")
    If Len(InputString) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no input
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("InputData")
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range("Q3:Q14")
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = sws.Range("P3:P14")
    
    Dim srIndex As Variant
    srIndex = Application.Match(CLng(InputString), slrg, 0)
    If IsError(srIndex) Then Exit Sub ' month (number) not found
    Dim sMonth As String: sMonth = srrg.Cells(srIndex)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    
    For Each dws In wb.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, dws.Name, sMonth, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next dws
    
    If dws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' worksheet not foundd
    
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
    
    dws.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like you want to evaluate the formula in your code and read the output of that into a variable, then use that variable as the sheet name? If so then try the following:

```
    Dim DestWS1 As Worksheet
    Dim InputValue As Integer
    InputValue = InputBox("Please enter your month index number", "Selecting month index to generate your report")
    
    ' Print the name of the airport to the Immediate Window(Ctrl + G)

        Dim MonthIndexResult As String
        
        ' MonthIndexResult = _
        ' "=LOOKUP(" & InputValue & ",InputData!R3C17:R14C17,InputData!R3C16:R14C16)"
        MonthIndexResult = Application.Evaluate("=LOOKUP(" & InputValue & ",InputData!R3C17:R14C17,InputData!R3C16:R14C16)")

Set DestWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MonthIndexResult)
DestWS1.Select
```

You can find out more about this method here: [Application.Evaluate method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)

Comment: Unfortunately, it Didn't work with me